# Why do so many people seem incapable of following the rules?

Tags: politics

Why can't people keep their politics out of forums that don't involve politics? Politics is like an infection that spreads to every place where people have conversations, even when the place is specifically about other subjects. Football players feel the need to make political statements during opening ceremonies, musicians feel the need to tell us how they feel about the current president, and people in philosophy forums feel the need to make a political point about whatever issue is currently in vogue.

Is the minimal self control needed to keep your political opinion to yourself really beyond the capacities of so many people?

Comment: The body doesn't match the title. In the Lahaina fire, the cops blocked off the only road out of town. People who obeyed burned to death; those who disobeyed, survived. We often find this in crisis situations. During normal times, following the rules works. During life-threatening emergencies, following your own instincts and judgment is the best survival strategy. But then I read the body of your question, and it has nothing at all to do with that. Can you clarify your question? You seem annoyed about something rather nonspecific. Are these political commentators in the room with us now?

Comment: Because emotions trump rules, especially when they come from perceived moral righteousness while the rules are merely pragmatic. People's politics is people's virtue in action, or so they project it to themselves, and what stands in the way of virtue be damned. But this is a psychology question.

Comment: Talk about calling the kettle black... Of course this has nothing to do with philosophy. vote to close.

Comment: Your post was a political opinion, about politics being bad. Why didn't you keep it for yourself? :-)

Comment: @armand but the Answers do. Who was that old guy who was killed for his statements, S somebody...?

Comment: Your question betrays a certain irritation, which doesn't help. On the face of it, almost everything has a political aspect, in a certain sense of political, and if philosophy cannot have political implications, at least sometimes, it must avoid many important issues. That seems a pity. But there is a real problem, and that is to prevent the storms of public debate on, for example, Twitter/X, from invading and preventing philosophical discussion. It is not the subject matter, but the approach to the subject matter that makes a discussion philosophical.

Comment: Defining a philosophical discussion is extremely difficult. The rules as we have them are an attempt to do so. It would be good to open a discussion with a view to improving on that attempt. That discussion could be framed, but it would be a meta-discussion, wouldn't it?

Comment: So, the question is about following the rules, for societal peace, I think? And the assertion is that a lack of self-control mars the public sphere with issues from other areas. Yes? I'm guessing that if people had more self-control in general, and were more civic-minded, politics would be so boring that no one would care about it. It is kind of an X-Y problem: politics intruding is the symptom of a different issue entirely. It would be great if people were less selfish. I've never seen a solution to that, but remain hopeful.

Comment: @ScottRowe "I'm guessing that if people had more self-control in general, and were more civic-minded, politics would be so boring that no one would care about it." I don't deny that boring political (and non-political) discussions are perfectly possible, even common. There are various reasons why that might happen. But it is perfectly possible to engage in an interesting and sometimes productive discussion about all sorts of serious issues. I see that frequently on this site and elsewhere.

Comment: @LudwigV sure, 'boring' to some, doesn't have to mean unimportant or not needing any discussion. I could talk a lot about programming or radio antennas. I just get concerned when discussion inevitably leads to storming Capitols, firing rockets, riots, etc. Maybe we need a thorough and dull tour through the meta-discussion you proposed, prior to any actual discussion? The Question raises an issue, although sort of backwards: why are people so easily riled and turned in to mobs? Why is any proper issue worth so much emotion? Well, Psychology rather than Philosophy I guess...

Comment: Well, I'm very interested in the question why rational or at least reasonable discussion is so fragile and so often disrupted - as if other ways of resolving issues were better, which they are demonstrably not. Nothing seems to have come out of Psychology so far - though I may well be wrong. So I don't see any harm in philosophers discussing it when they see the need. We might at least formulate a question that some psychologist might want to take on.

Answer (score 2):

There's **a social convention** that we set aside politics for the sake of comity in the public sphere, but it's not a legal standard in most situations, and it's arguably not a moral standard in many situations either.

Legally, in the US, you can't discuss politics at an actual election site. And many workplaces forbid it formally or informally. And **yes, it's boorish around the Thanksgiving dinner table** when you won't shut up about it.

But politics is a catchall term for a wide range of things important in people's lives, ranging from core morals and values to human rights. In the case of athletes and entertainers, they are often using the platform of their fame and popularity as a way to speak out--as private citizens--about issues of personal importance to them or people who are like them. It's their right to do that, and in some cases, **it may arguably even be a moral duty**. Often, the demand that they shut up can be traced back to those who are benefiting from an unfair situation not wanting it to be publicly aired.

Answer (score 2):

Your analysis of the situation is in itself a political statement that tries to determine when and where politics can come up in daily life.

At the root of it is the problem that it is genuinely difficult to escape the concept of politics whenever interactions with other people or depictions of those interactions are involved. That is because the choice not to raise a topic or to bar its raising is in itself a specific position that has implications on how power is distributed in the current group, even if the venue seems innocuous or neutral.

The other aspect to consider is that 'apolitical' is often meant to mean 'corresponding to the politics I believe in'. So for instance an athlete might choose to perform a visible sign of protest before a game, and be called out for it, but the audience doing the calling out will not perceive the other aspects of the 'usual' run of the game as political, such as the display of the national flag for instance. A person might see the presence of a gender other than male in the choice of a video game character as political, even though the 'normal' choice from their POV has its own political implications.

In truth, there is no such thing as a place where politics do not exist. Are musical and sports venues neutral when we know that those have been banned or made illegal at various points in history? Is a philosophy forum suddenly off limits when the ability to freely debate philosophy is itself not something that has been politically available to all people in all eras?

Comment: Please keep contributing here.